# creating window in child thread in vc++

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2010, process, visual-c++

I want to create a window and show some image display (like animation based on `SetTimer()`) on window created using `CreateWindow()` function. But it should be created on separate thread and should remain alive until user closes this. I tried but was unsuccessful.

**EDITED**

I just googled I found this link [How To Create Windows in a Multithreaded Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90975/en-us) but one thing i want to know when `Window Procedure` get invoked. if it is invoked by system then how i can call it from my `child thread`.

Comment: well, i created 3 function 1> `showWindow()` which just create window and displays (called from Child thread). 2> `SetTimer()` to set time interval (500ms) for loading image (called from Child Thread). 3> `LoadImage()` to load image (called from `WindowsProc`'s `WM_PAINT` event). But my window seems to freeze and cursors show busy icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows (represented by HWNDs) in Windows have a thread affinity. Their WindowProc is always invoked in the context of the thread they are created with.

As such, they are a convenient way to serialize calls between threads as the PostMessage and SendMessage APIs can be called from any thread in the application, but the WindowProc will get executed in the context of the original creating thread.

Because `WM_TIMER` messages posted to message queues are the mechanism by which SetTimer works, again you need to be careful when calling SetTimer in a multithreaded app - The timer messages will be processed by the calling thread (if the hwnd parameter is NULL) or the window's thread.

You also, as a result, have to be careful to put a message loop on every thread that might create windows, or want to process timers.

Comment: can you tell me how to invoke `WindowProc` from child thread?

Comment: As I said - if you call SendMessage, or PostMessage from a thread different to the windows thread, then the WindowProc will be invoked in its own thread.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your user-interface on the main Windows thread.  Setting a timer using the Windows API doesn't require an additional thread (as your `WndProc` will get the timer message `WM_TIMER`).

Even if you have a long running task to perform that might necessitate the use of an additional thread, keep the window on the main thread, do your work in the worker-thread and post back to the main thread with updates.

Comment: let me tell u why i am doing so. actually I need to show images taken from webcam on Windows Login (some kind of face detection) where I added some extra contols like username, password and domain box. if i call `CreateWindow` that time it does not show controls. it only show controls on Login UI after I close my custom window.